# How to set footnotes in ‘small’ size

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, documentclass-writing

Footnotes are set is `\footnotesize`. For some conference paper style, essentially `\footnotesize` is redefined to be `\small`. The choice to set footnotes in ‘small’ size is fine. The fact that in the way it is done currently the original `\footonotesize` is not available anymore, e.g., for in figures, is a downside.

I am modernizing the paper style (creating a class file). *How can I get footnotes set in `\small` while not touching the standard size definitions?*

The class file is based on the standard `article` class. I also use the following other possibly relevant packages:

- `footmisc` (for its `bottom` option)
- `titling`
- `titlesec`
- `hyperref`

Comment: Some classes (and maybe packages) redefine `\footnote`, so without knowing the class you are starting from there is no way to tell.

Comment: @campa: Thanks for your valid remark. I have mentioned the base class and some possibly relevant packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the original definition of `\footnote`.

```
% footnotesizeprob.tex  SE 572020

\documentclass{article}
\let\Footnotesize=\footnotesize  % save the definition
\let\footnotesize=\huge  % make a footnotesize change very visible
\begin{document}

Regular text.\footnote{with a footnote}

{\footnotesize Text in footnotesize.}
%
{\small Text in small.}
%
{\Footnotesize Text in Footnotesize.}
\end{document}
```

You can now use `\Footnotesize` to get the original `\footnotesize` definition.

I think that the conference paper style creators were lazy in what they did. If they wanted footnotes to be typeset in `\small` then they should have changed the `\footnotetext` code, not eliminating the original `\foonotesize`. --- GOM

Answer (score 1):

The selection of `\footnotesize` happens in the definition of `\footnotetext`. `footmisc` does extensive customizations of the `\footnotetext` macro, always explicitly requesting `\footnotesize`. Arguably, `\footnotesize` should refer to the size of footnote text and not a specific size in the range (you can always create another macro, say, `\smaller` to set text at that size a little smaller than `\small` and not use `\footnotesize` for anything but indicating the size of footnote text.

Another option would be to use `etoolbox`’s `\patchcmd` to replace `\footnotesize` with `\small` in `\footnotetext` (you'll want to put the `\patchcmd` in the `\AtBeginDocument` hook so that it will take effect after any packages have been loaded). I don't have a working LaTeX at the moment since my laptop is in for repairs so I can't test anything I throw together.